# Why does my html import tag not work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been looking at code reusability (for example) and have been experimenting with HTML import tags. I want to auto include my bootstrap code in every webpage and would like to do it with one line of code as opposed to multiple.

After doing some research online, the answer seemed to be to use the  tag, most namely the following format:

```
<head>
    <import rel="import" href="includes/bootstrap.html">
</head>
```

My bootstrap.html file is just some normal bootstrap links as follows:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm simply trying to avoid importing the same three lines across all my pages. However, my browser (Chrome) does not seem to implement include in any way, even when I use for reasons other than Bootstrap.

How should I properly include my bootstrap files across the head of all my pages?

Alex

Comment: can you check console logs?

Comment: Because there is no `import` element definition in the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/).

Comment: Unfortunately empty!
I'm not sure I'm using the import statement for the right reason. I'm basically trying to squeeze those 3 lines (6 lines w/ comments) of code into one so that it will be cleaner as I build more webpages.

Comment: @Alexander I'm not quite sure what you mean. I've been looking at pages such as:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports

And 
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Comment: @alexp2603, the `link` tag is not `import`. The `import` is value of link `rel` attribute. See detais in the [HTML Imports](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/) Working Draft.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer if you want.
Further question - is this best practice for linking files such as bootstrap across a website?

Comment: It is recommended to create a new question post to describe specific problem and highlight details. But you should be careful and read [ask] before ask such questions as "What is best practice... ?" to avoid off-topic flag receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change import tag to link tag

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="includes/bootstrap.html">
</head>
```

Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports)

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a header file 'header.php' with the links like so,

```
<head>
<title>Your Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</head>
```

And when you write your code just include the header.php part.

```
<html>
<? include ("header.php");?>
</html>
```

Comment: That's originally what I had in mind, but I thought it may have been better to keep it html instead of bringing in php